# VLC and Autohotkey

Tags: vlc-media-player, autohotkey

Has anyone had any success getting Autohotkey to work with VLC?

```
^numpad6::
DetectHiddenWindows , On
ControlSend , ahk_parent, !{right}, VLC Media Player
DetectHiddenWindows , Off
return

^numpad4::    
DetectHiddenWindows , On
ControlSend , ahk_parent, !{left}, VLC Media Player ahk_class QWidget
DetectHiddenWindows , Off  
return

^#space:: 
DetectHiddenWindows , On
ControlSend , ahk_parent, {space}, ahk_class QWidget
DetectHiddenWindows , Off
return
```

Used these (a different method for each one) and they're not working.  The scripts work with Itunes btw.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use VLC HTTP Interface LIbrary, I hope that could help you...
This is a library of the http interface commands for VLC Media Player.

Here are some advantages of using VLCHTTP and VLC Media Player:

- VLC does NOT need to be the active window to use HTTP functions and therefore doesn't interfere with other windows.
- HTTP functions can be used over the internet, local networks or on one computer.
- VLC can play full screen on any monitor, not just the default monitor.
- VLC will open full screen on which ever monitor the media link was clicked.
- VLC does not drop out of full screen when it looses focus. Play a movie on one monitor and work on the other.

Example:

```
Gui, Add, Button, gButton1, Play/Pause
Gui, Add, Button, gButton2, Volume Up
Gui, Show
Return

Button1:
VLCHTTP_Pause() ; Use pause instead of play to toggle play/pause mode.
Return

Button2:
VLCHTTP_VolumeUp(1) ; Turns the volume up 1 step.
Return
```

More info can be found at [this link](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64266-vlc-http-interface-library/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for leting me know that, as you can see I`m still new here and I`m learning, but want to help as much as I can :)

Comment: No problem! Please just [edit] your answer and tell us what that link talks about instead of just posting the link. That way people know what to expect, et cetera. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your ControlSend command should probably have different parameters (read the help file for more information). This works on my PC (Win7 32):

```
^#Space::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
ControlSend, , {space}, VLC media player
Return
```

It turns out that you don't need any control ID: VLC will accept space in any control (or at least the topmost control). The problem with your code was, I think, that you used both window class and text from the title to identify the window: you should just use one or the other, not both.

I always set the title match mode to 2 (= words can be anywhere in the title) because that catches most titles and works more intuitively (I am too lazy to test whether it works with a different match mode).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with IfWinExist so that you only have to specify the VLC parent name once.  Here's the code that I use.

```
#IfWinExist ahk_class QWidget
Media_Next::
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, n  ; Next
    return

Media_Prev::
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, p  ; Previous
    return

Media_Play_Pause::
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Space}  ; Play/Pause
    return

Media_Stop::
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, s  ; Stop
    return

#IfWinExist
```